# How to split a string every 4 chars and then memorize the fragments

Tags: c, string, split

Does anybody know how to split a string every (e.g.) 4 chars?
My message (contained in a char buffer) is "Have a nice day", and I want to split it so that it appears in the following way:
"Have\0"
" a n\0"
"ice \0"
"day \0".
Every split is contained in a char* temp[5].
The function "strtok" splits only by using spaces, and I need to split the chars of my message  every 4 byte...I really don't know how to do, will somebody help me please?

Comment: You'll need a loop, along with some calls to `malloc` (and `free`). Give it a go, and only ask a Stack Overflow question when you've got stuck.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth yeah, this is such a basic question for which asking for a solution shows either no effort or fundamental lack of programming-related common sense...

Comment: Actually, I asked this question because I got stuck :P

Answer (score 3):

```
const char *str = "have a nice day "; // 16 chars to be divisible by 4, else the last strndup won't work properly...
size_t len = strlen(str);

const char **fragments;
fragments = malloc(sizeof(*fragments) * len / 4);
int i;

for (i = 0; i < (len / 4); i++)
{
    fragments[i] = strndup(str + 4 * i, 4);
}
```

Now fragments should contain the, well, fragments...

Comment: 1) you need to allocate space for the nul-terminators, too  2) you must round up: the last chunk may be smaller than 4 bytes.

Comment: @wildplasser I see the point in 2) however I added a comment at the first line regarding this. **but**: where do I need to 'allocate for the terminating NUL'? strndup() adds it anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I saw a strncpy() (I am allergic for strncpy), but it was a strndup() Mybad.

Comment: @wildplasser No problem at all. :-)

Comment: @user411313 no, but being standard wasn't in OP's question (anyway it's POSIX and it's available on almost all systems one should care about...)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *split(const char *str, size_t size){
    static const char *p=NULL;
    char *temp;
    int i;
    if(str != NULL) p=str;
    if(p==NULL || *p=='\0') return NULL;
    temp=(char*)malloc((size+1)*sizeof(char));
    for(i=0;*p && i<size;++i){
        temp[i]=*p++;
    }
    temp[i]='\0';
    return temp;
}

int main(){
    char *p = "Have a nice day";
    char *temp[5];
    int i,j;

    for(i=0;NULL!=(p=split(p, 4));p=NULL)
        temp[i++]=p;

    for(j=0;j<i;++j){
        printf("\"%s\"\n", temp[j]);
        free(temp[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you know where I can get more info on the line: for(i=0;NULL!=(p=split(p, 4));p=NULL)

Answer (score 0):

A C string is a NULL-terminated array of `char`s. You can use a combination of pointer arithmetics and `memcpy`:

```
const char* originalString = "Have a nice day";

char str1[5];
char str2[5];
memcpy(str1, originalString, 4);
str1[4] = 0;
memcpy(str2, originalString + 4, 4);
str2[4] = 0;
```

Comment: Your memcpy()s without NUL-termination will segfault the prog...

Comment: @H2CO3 Forgot the null-termination, but I quickly added it.

Comment: This is a good first strep and the OP can add a loop to make it do what he really wants.

Comment: The memcpy itself would not segfault but trying to use the resulting strings with C string functions would.

Comment: @DavidGrayson of course that's what I meant.

Comment: Dear @H2CO3, I actually have a "lack of programming-related common sense", but know that Luchian Grigore (thanks for your tip) gave me a push, I can proceed to write my code :P

Comment: @AndreaMazzocchi let's say that's more than cool :)

Comment: You are wrong. A C string is a char-array with terminating '\0'. A string **literal** is a read-only char-array (with terminating '\0'), but this was not the question.

Comment: @user411313 you're absolutely right, that's what I had in mind. Edited, thanks for the spot!

Answer (score 0):

```
char** split(char* input)
{
    int count = (strlen(input) + 3) / 4;
    char** splitted = (char**)malloc(count * sizeof(char*));
    char** currentSplitted = splitted;
    while (*input != 0)
    {
        *currentSplitted = strndup(input, 4);
        input += strlen(*currentSplitted++);
    }

    return splitted;
}

int main()
{
    char* input = "Have a nice day";
    char** splitted = split(input);
    return 0;
}
```

You can get the source code for strndup at http://opensource.apple.com/source/gcc/gcc-5666.3/libiberty/strndup.c if you don't have it.

Answer (score 0):

You should separate your work in a function and sscanf can split the string.
For a constant splitsize at compiletime you can iterate with pointers over the new N+1 char-size like:

```
char (*split4chars(char *s,char (*b)[5]))[5]
{ /* returns a pointer to char[5] elements */
  int n;
  while( 1==sscanf(s,"%4[^\n]%n",*b++,&n) ) s+=n;
  return --b;
}

int main()
{
  char *s = "Have a nice day";
  char (*b)[5] = malloc(ceil(strlen(s)/4)*5), /* enough memory for destination */
       (*e)[5] = split4chars(s,b);

  while( e!=b ) /* iterate from begin to end here */
    puts(*b++);

  return 0;
}
```